# What are IBEP20 _lp and address _wbnb parameter in BnbStaking.sol

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, defi, pancakeswap

I am trying to deploy bnbstaking.sol for my own project by cloning pancakeswap-farm [repository](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-farm). The farm repository has other contracts of MasterChef, Souschef, CakeToken and SyrupBar. For farming all these contracts need to be deployed. I have deployed successfully the remaining smart contracts. If anyone has cloned pancakeswap can they guide me a bit. I do not understand what these two parameters (**IBEP20 _lp and address _wbnb** ) are and what to assign them . This is the github [link](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-farm/blob/master/contracts/BnbStaking.sol).
[image]

Comment: Voting to close this, as this is a question to the person who originally write the code, third parties cannot comment random pieces of code.

Comment: lp probably is Liquidity Provider, a token issued to the liquidity providers, and wbnb I guess is a sort of wrapped ether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_lp is the Pancake liquidity provider token to stake in the farm pool and wbnb is a wrapped BNB token on Binance Smart Chain.

Comment: Okay thanks will try this out.